# QSharedMemory inconsistent behaviour in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, shared-memory

I'm playing with `QSharedMemory` and I'm not sure if I just found a serious bug or I'm doing something wrong. The case is that docs say that `QSharedMemory::create()` should return true if no memory with the same key exists, otherwise it should return false and `QSharedMemory::error()` should be checked to see what happened.

My current code is:

```
QSharedMemory sm("smtest");
sm.setKey("smtest"); // <--- not needed as I already set the key in the initializator, but I'm leaving it anyways, just for the test
qDebug() << sm.create(1);
qDebug() << sm.create(1); //<--- I expect this to return false, but it returns true.
qDebug() << sm.error(); //<--. I expect this to return QSharedMemory::AlreadyExists, but QSharedMemory::NoError is returned instead.
//wtf?!
```

My question is: did I just found a really big bug in Qt4 or I'm doing something wrong?

PS: This code is ran on Windows 7 x64

EDIT: Just to make it clear, if I run that code twice, the second app should detect the first one, but it doesn't.

EDIT 2: I reported a bug here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27744

Comment: This is just a guess, docs don't say, but it appears calling `create` many times from the same thread returns true... why would you want to call it many times from same thread anyway?

Comment: @hyde That was just a test. Anyways, if I run the same application two times I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run this on Linux:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QSharedMemory>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSharedMemory sm("smtest");
    sm.setKey("smtest"); // <--- not needed as I already set the key in the initializator, but I'm leaving it anyways, just for the test
    qDebug() << sm.create(1);
    qDebug() << sm.create(1); //<--- I expect this to return false, but it returns true.
    qDebug() << sm.error(); //<--. I expect this to return QSharedMemory::AlreadyExists, but QSharedMemory::NoError is returned instead.
    //wtf?!
    return 0;
}
```

and on first run got

```
true
false 
4
```

Could it be that you don't have QCoreApplication created? A lot of Qt stuff tends to depend on that being created.

Edit: to emphasize, above only happens with first run. Subsequent runs give false-false always.

Edit2: On Windows, result is true-true for me too.

Edit3: Seems to be a bug, sounds awfully lot like this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-5123

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not screweing up something, I copy/paste your code in QtCreator and I got ```true, true, 4```  (so, it keeps bugging somewhere).

Comment: Actually, I only get that on first run. Deleting the file (reported by `sm.nativeKey()`) and running again still gives false-false. Changing the key name gives true-false for the first run again.

Comment: Yeah, the fact is that Qt, for some reason, is returning true after each .create(), no matter if that key already exists or not.

Comment: That could also be a Windows feature, and not necessarily a bug... How Shared memory actually works is a bit system dependent (as is also explained in the docs, though it doesn't explain this behaviour). In that case it's still a documentation bug, I'd say.

Comment: Well... that sucks... Is there any way to detect if there is already a shared memory with this key?

Comment: Just tried with Win, also got true-true. Probably there's no way, other than creating a guaranteed-unique key (like by using a UUID). You might try asking a refined question "How to create unique Qt shared memory key under Windows".

Comment: No, I'm not asking for a unique key. I'm trying to check if my app is already running. (Yes, I know this can be done with QLocalSocket, but I really feel that this is an overkill). QSharedMemory should just work. Damn trolls! :p

Comment: After doing some more tests, it seems that QSharedMemory in Windows is completely broken. .attach() seems to return randomly true/false, and when false is returned, .error() returns NoError.

Comment: Augmented answer with link to apparently relevant bug report, no workaround though :(. I'd go to #qt-labs at freenode to ask for advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bug, please read my bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27765

I lately attached a patch to fix this. If you want this to be fixed you need to vote.

Comment: Today there were changes in the issue! :)